# Explanation of range with slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, slice

How did `456` become `459`?

```
>>> a = range(123, 456, 7)[1::4]  
>>> print(a)
range(130, 459, 28)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your results are essentially *the same*.

In python 3 `range`s are [*immutable sequences*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), in python 2 they return a list:

```
a = range(123, 456, 7)[1::4]  # generate a range spaced 7 apart, take every 4th
```

python 2.7:

```
print(a) 
> [130, 158, 186, 214, 242, 270, 298, 326, 354, 382, 410, 438]
```

pyton 3.6:

```
print(a)
> range(130, 459, 28)

print(*range(130, 459, 28))
> 130 158 186 214 242 270 298 326 354 382 410 438
```

Your slicing tells the `range` to only take every 4th element for its 7-spaced-apart range. `4*7 == 28`: that is why the `range` "changes".

The *recalculated* range-slice changes its upper bound to startvalue + multiple of your stepsize - and the upper bound of the `range` is exclusive, so it does not really matter if it is called `456` or `459` or `439` - as long as it is bigger then the number you generate last from the range.

Comment: Python 3's `range` objects *are not* iterators. You can iterate over them repeatedly. You also can't directly call `next` on one (you need to pass it to `iter` first, to get an actual iterator).

Comment: Python 3 `range` isn't an iterator. It's still a sequence. It just generates items on demand now.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for the correction, fixed, added ref to documentation

Answer (score 1):

To begin with.

```
a = range(123, 456, 7)
print(list(a))
#[123, 130, 137, 144, 151, 158,.....431, 438, 445, 452]
```

i.e we get a list from 123 to 456, with a step size of 7

Then we try the next step.

```
a = range(123, 456, 7)[1::4]
print(list(a))
#[130, 158, 186, 214, 242, 270, 298, 326, 354, 382, 410, 438]
```

Which is equivalent to range with start of 130, with a step size of 28, and the last value is 459, which is `range(130, 459, 28)`, which also tells you to take every 4th element from the range, starting from the 1st element.

Answer (score 0):

Note this also happens if you make a slice that doesn't change anything:

```
>>> b = range(123, 456, 7)
>>> print(b[::1])
range(123, 459, 7)
```

The last number included in that range is 452, so any value `452 < stop <= 459` would give you the same output. Given that the first value that isn't included is the stop with a step of 1, it's more consistent to use that for other steps too; it allows you to quickly determine what the last value that *is* included will be by subtracting the step from the stop.

---

What I *don't* know, though, is why that logic isn't followed for the new step of 28; on that basis it would be helpful if the result was:

```
>>> b[1::4]
range(130, 466, 28)
```

so you could easily work out that the last value included was 438. However, any value `438 < stop <= 466` will give the same output, so 459 isn't exactly wrong.